# Need to bind data

Tags: html, angularjs

Following is my code, I need to bind data to ng-model, when I bind ng-model = "value", I can see the value in the text field, but I want to update the value on changing the text input.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="action in model.editAction"> 
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in action | orderBy: '-key'">
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  
            ng-model="model.editAction.value" name = "key"
            required/>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="main.AssetURL.$error.required ">Service name</span> 
        </td>
        <td> {{ action.DESCRIPTION }} </td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: "I can see the value in the text field, but I want to update the value on changing the text input" update it where? its not clear

Comment: When you change the "value", I mean, the text in ng-model, the `model.editAction.value` will be updated. I don't understand what do you need

Answer (score 0):

In your controller define a $scope var like this:

```
$scope.value
```

In your input, place just value inside ng-model:

```
ng-model="value"
```

This way you are binding values between your view and your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change for getting the new values which you input

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  
        ng-model="model.editAction.value" name = "key"  ng-change="onChangeValue(model.editAction.value)"
       required/>
```

And in your controller,

```
   $scope.onChangeValue=function(value){
   console.log(value);
  //you should see the new updated value
  }
```